# User Multiple Roles in MySQL Database

Tags: database-design

I need to assign 4 roles.
The role has User , Manager , Admin , Super Admin

and some User will have 2 roles

each role There will be different personal information.
and giving a role to User will go through Register

I'm not sure what's the best way to create a table.

I'm supposed to create 4 tables separated by roles.
Or how should I create the table?

I would also like to know how to set roles for page access. or query MySql

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating 3 tables:

`users`

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John doe | superadmin@gg.com |
| 2 | carry | admin@gg.com |
| 3 | bobby | manager@gg.com |
| 4 | Phillip | user@gg.com |

`roles`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | Super Admin |
| 6 | Admin |
| 7 | Manager |
| 8 | User |

`user_has_roles`

| user_id | role_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 4 | 8 |

Assign a role to a user by passing `role_id` and `user_id` in `user_has_roles` table. [Sample schema](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/76gbeq4uQ5RLKcffPGaDcG/0).

Answer (score -1):

Created two tables will be needed. One table for roles with (userid and roles_name), another table for the user table with (roles_id) column, roles_id is foreign key from the roles table.